# how to change <a href =" "> dynamically as per user role

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

in my project having different **admin role**, 
on click of button link  want to check his role and show the page as per his role,
how can  do this in **jsp** file?
can write function onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by conditionally showing the link. That is show/hide link based on the user's role. Spring security Tag Libraries will help you for that. 
Example:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <td><a href="<c:url value="/page1.htm"/>">Admin Access Page</a></td>
</sec:authorize>
```

For more info check [this.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html)